# 'work' and 'from across' usage

Tags: prepositions

> Our shelves display the **work** of 35 artisans **from across** the region.

In this sentence, Did 35 artisans make only one work collaboratively?
or Did 35 artisans make their work respectively?

and I saw answer in this site that explains 'from across' means 'from every part of', and I was wondering if 'from across' can always mean 'from every part of' in any sentences. (then I can write that in my vocabulary note and memorize it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"From across (some region)" means "from one side of the region to the other", which *figuratively* does mean "from every part of the region".

Since it's not specifically mentioned there is no reason to think that all the artisans collaborated on a single piece.  Here "work" is an uncountable (or *mass*) noun meaning [*artwork*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/artwork) -- all of the individual pieces by all of the artisans.  Example:

> This month the museum will feature **work** by various Impressionist painters.

Side note:  There is a difference between an *artist* and an [*artisan*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/artisan).  While there is often some element of *artistry* in what artisans do, an artisan is someone proficient in a *trade*, who generally makes items that have both practical and aesthetic value.

For example, a particularly skilled cheesemaker could be called both an *artisan*, and an *artist with cheese*.   The cheese has practical value in that it can be eaten, but how the cheesemaker selects and combines ingredients can be considered an *art*.